# how to ignore charset errors while parsing pdf with pdf miner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, unicode, pdfminer

Hi folks I got an encoding error while parsing a pdf file using pdf miner.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from pdfminer import layout

from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextBoxHorizontal, LTTextContainer
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
import pdfminer

#pageno=0
#for page_layout in extract_pages("./Statements/Manoj Kotak.pdf"):
#    pageno+=1
#    print(str(len(page_layout))+" page No:"+str(pageno))
#    for element in page_layout:
#        if(isinstance(element,LTTextBoxHorizontal)):
#            
#            print(element.get_text())
#    if pageno==2:
#        break


#Open Pdf 
fp=open("../pathto/pdffile.pdf")

#Pdf Parser Instantiation
parser =PDFParser(fp)

#Reading Parsed Document

document=PDFDocument(parser)

#Text Extraction is Implementable

if not document.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

#Initiating Resource Manager to store Shared Objects in Pdf document
rsrmgr=PDFResourceManager()

#Begining Page Layout Analysis
# Parameters for analysis
laparams=LAParams()

#Device Initialsation
device=PDFPageAggregator(rsrmgr,laparams=laparams)


# PDF interpreter Initialisation
interpreter=PDFPageInterpreter(rsrmgr,device)

#Function to Parse Parsed Pdf Object
def parse_obj(layout_objs):
        # looping Through the Pdf 
        for obj in layout_objs:
            if isinstance(obj,pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                print ("%6 %6 %s".format(obj.bbox[0],obj.bbox[1],obj.get_text()))

for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        layout=device.get_result()

        parse_obj(layout.objs)
```

Above is the source code I have been used for parsing pdf in python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin\statementparser.py", line 37, in <module>
    document=PDFDocument(parser)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 571, in __init__
    pos = self.find_xref(parser)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 788, in find_xref
    for line in parser.revreadlines():
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py", line 267, in revreadlines
    s = self.fp.read(prevpos-pos)
  File "D:\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1803: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: PDF is a binary format, so you should open the file in binary mode, not text mode, ie. specify `open(path, mode="rb")` rather than omitting `mode`, which defaults to `"rt"`. I don't know the `pdfminer` library, but I'd expect it to accept (even require) a binary file handle.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you specify the file mode as 'rb' to open the file in binary read mode, because by default *'open'* loads the file in read only more.
In your original code, the file path was set as follows:

```
fp = open("../pathto/pdffile.pdf")
```

You should update it to something like:

```
fp = open("../path/to/pdffile.pdf", 'rb')
```

Additionally You could add f-string formatting to the print statement for a more structured output, like;

```
print(f"X: {obj.bbox[0]}, Y: {obj.bbox[1]}, Text: {obj.get_text()}")
```

Comment: It looks like you had a good idea for addressing the OP's problem, but your post is not very useful as a Stack-Overflow answer. Code-only answers tend to be unhelpful, and in this case most of the code is copied from the question, so adds no new information. Your answer might be good if you just showed what needs change, and explained why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks For Guiding, I'll Keep These Things In My Mind The Next Time.

Comment: No need to wait for next time: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68049104/edit) your post to improve it.